# Which is more important either an adjective or article?

Tags: ielts, listening

I have just finished a practice test for Ielts, and I looked at the key. There is a question in listening part asking about what the speaker said for a course requirement, the exam must be completed by using NO MORE THAN 3 WORDS

The question number 26 is what I want to ask about.

[image]

The speaker said: *"You’ll have to **give a small talk** to your tutorial group for 25 minutes . . ."*

Since you have to use NO MORE THAN 3 WORDS, you have very few options here.

1. give a talk
2. give small talk
3. a small talk

As you can see, there is the word "must" at the end of the line above, which means the option 3. isn't the right one.

```
Scroll left to see the given answer by its key.                          Its key states that option 1. is the correct answer.
```

`Thanks`

Comment: Maybe it won't answer your question but at least give some hints:
https://ielts.allearsenglish.com/word-count-rules-ielts-writing/
1) 'a' counts as a word
2) I was considering small-talk to be hyphenated but actually it is not: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/small%20talk

Comment: Hi hbtpoprock, this particular question is trivial for native speakers and such questions are usually off-topic on this site; please consider the [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) (ELL) Stack Exchange instead.

Comment: @linguisticturn I used to use it before, but received worse feedback and less efficient answer maybe because this platform has more traffic in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Give small talk for 25 minutes* is not acceptable English. Since *small talk* appears without an article, it would be most naturally interpreted as an uncountable compund noun, namely [*small talk*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/small-talk), meaning 'conversation about things that are not important, often between people who do not know each other well'. But *small talk* is not something that we 'give' (instead, we [*make*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22make+small+talk%22) or [*conduct*](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&tbm=bks&ei=4kXXW67BLNGa_Qarip_oBA&q=%22conduct+small+talk%22&oq=%22conduct+small+talk%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...3952.5294.0.5920.7.7.0.0.0.0.75.487.7.7.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.gPECV2S9onA) it). Moreover, it makes no sense in the context.

On the other hand, *give a talk for 25 minutes* makes perfect sense. Moreover, if you said *give a **small** talk for 25 minutes,* you wouldn't really add any new information, as the assigned duration of the talk (25 minutes) completely specifies the size of the talk.

Comment: Plus a 25-minute talk is not exactly ‘small’ in the context of students taking a class. It would be small if you were Fidel Castro, but small talks in class are usually more like five minutes than 25.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Fair enough...